# On my Wi-Fi network, a Safari URL that contains an IP address is always redirected to Google search

Tags: iphone, ios, mobile-safari

When connected to my Wi-Fi network, my iPhone (iOS 15.4.1) always opens Google search when I use Safari to try to connect to my local website using an IP address like https://192.168.1.1:3000.

This also happens with any website if the URL contains an IP address, like this https://123.45.678.90/contact.html.

What should I do to turn the search temporarily off? Is there a shortcut or setting? How can I reach my localhost page?

Comment: Are you on wifi or your telco connection when this happens? [I can't test this as my Gateway specifically rejects non-ethernet LAN connections for security] but to your telco, this is not a local address. It's only local on your home LAN.

Comment: @Tetsujin I'm on wifi, my home wlan router routs my web.

Comment: What is your iPhone's IP address when connected to Wi-Fi?

Comment: @jaume usually its dynamic with DHCP. But for test case I set it stable, 192.168.1.111. Access try to `https://192.168.1.111:3000` triggers Google search

Comment: Where is the local website installed, on your iPhone? I ask because in your question you write that `https://192.168.1.1:3000` is redirected to Google, but in your comment you write `https://192.168.1.111:3000`, which one is it?

Comment: @jaume I was just meaning, any address written with this schema, end up with the Google search. The local serverruns on another, desktop machine, which uses the same wlan. Its IP is `192.168.1.11`.

Comment: I experience this behavior of the combobox with any address, which contains IP address, not only with my own locally hosted website. I can input any address without DNS resolution, like `https://123.45.678.90/contact.html` - this end up with Google search too.